# Cómo reordenar una matriz en Numpy, de la forma Matriz = [Identidad | Residuo], sólo moviendo columnas de la matriz?

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

```
import numpy as np

_list = [[1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1,-1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,-1, 1, 0, 0]]

matrix = np.array(_list)
print(matrix)

print('=='*50)
```

Busco dentro de la matriz, una submatriz identidad (que para mi código siempre existirá),
y luego reordeno esta matriz, sólo moviendo columnas, de forma tal que la matriz quede así:

Matriz = [ Identidad | Residuo ]

```
# _list = [[1, 0, 0, 0,||-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#          [0, 1, 0, 0,|| 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#          [0, 0, 1, 0,|| 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1],
#          [0, 0, 0, 1,|| 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0]]

_list = [[1, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1, 0]]

matrix = np.array(_list)
print(matrix)
```

Alguna idea de cómo hacer esto, o quizás alguna función de Numpy que haga esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ha ocurrido la siguiente solución, aunque me parece lo suficientemente engorrosa como para sospechar que tiene que haber una forma más simple:

```
import numpy as np

_list = [[1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1, 1,-1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,-1, 1, 0, 0]]

matrix = np.array(_list)

I = np.identity(matrix.shape[0], dtype=int)
aux = set(tuple(c) for c in I.tolist())

residuo = []
for col in matrix.T:
  if tuple(col) in aux:
    aux.remove(tuple(col))
  else:
    residuo.append(col)

result = np.concatenate((I, np.array(residuo))).T
```

result:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0]])
```

### Explicación

Tras crear la matriz de entrada, creo también una matriz identidad, del tamaño adecuado (número de filas de la matriz de entrada):

```
>>> I = np.identity(matrix.shape[0], dtype=int)
>>> I
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

A partir de ella creo un conjunto auxiliar cuyos elementos son las columnas de `I`, pero como tuplas (el conjunto no garantiza orden, pero eso no influye en el método):

```
>>> aux = set(tuple(c) for c in I.tolist())
>>> aux
{(0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0)}
```

Seguidamente itero por cada columna de `matrix` (que es lo mismo que iterar por cada elemento de su traspuesta, `matrix.T`):

```
for col in matrix.T:
  if tuple(col) in aux:
    aux.remove(tuple(col))
  else:
    residuo.append(col)
```

Si la columna en cuestión está en el conjunto `aux`, es que es una columna de la matriz `I`, y por tanto **no** debe ir al residuo. Lo elimino también de `aux` por si aparece luego otra columna igual, repetida, que sí debería ir entonces al residuo.

Si la columna no está en `aux`, debe ir al residuo.

Finalmente creo la matriz resultado concatenando la matriz identidad `I` y el residuo, y hago la traspuesta de todo ello para que quede "horizontal":

```
result = np.concatenate((I, np.array(residuo))).T
```

Comment: Wow! Genial, funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice esto, ya que me di cuenta que también me sirve dejar sólo el residuo en la matriz.

```
matrix = np.array(_list).T

def fun_generate_residue_matrix(matrix, rows):
    I = np.identity(rows)
    i = 0
    pos = 0
    while pos < rows:
        if (matrix[i] == I[pos]).all():
            pos += 1
            matrix = np.delete(matrix, i, axis = 0)
            i = 0
        i += 1
    return print(matrix)

fun_generate_residue_matrix(matrix, 4)
```

Pero la respuesta de @abulafia funciona mucho mejor!

Comment: Es que (si no me equivoco), en esta implementación tuya esperas que las columnas "de la identidad" aparezcan dentro de la matriz en el mismo orden que en `I`. Es decir, la primera que buscas encontrar sería [1 0 0 0], y la siguiente en aparecer debería ser [0 1 0 0], etc. Pero en el ejemplo que pones no aparecen en ese orden, por eso tuve que inventar un conjunto de tuplas.